# Gerrit remove Need Verified +1 (Verified)

Tags: java, git, relational-database, h2, gerrit

I just installed a Gerrit server and wish to get rid of the 
Need Verified +1 (Verified) permission.
Our team would only like to +2 changes instead of doing both things.

I tried following the steps at http://review.coreboot.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_CVRW

```
DELETE FROM approval_categories      WHERE category_id = 'VRIF';
DELETE FROM approval_category_values WHERE category_id = 'VRIF';
```

But I'm running a H2 database and I guess I'm just not sure exactly how to edit it without using Java.

Comment: I don't know Gerrit, but I guess you can access the database from the [H2 Console](http://h2database.com/html/quickstart.html#h2_console) if you know the database URL, user name, and password.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry, I should have specified I'm not using Windows. This is running on Ubuntu Server 11 64-bit

Comment: I downloaded the .zip and tried to issue 

java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Shell

and is asked me for the URL and Driver, both of which I am unsure of. Gerrit listens on port 8080 by default, but I don't know if the actual H2 database is tied to that port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the gerrit gsql command to get interactive query support directly against the underlying SQL database: http://review.coreboot.org/Documentation/cmd-gsql.html

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit gsql
```

There you can issue the DELETE commands:

```
DELETE FROM approval_categories      WHERE category_id = 'VRIF';
DELETE FROM approval_category_values WHERE category_id = 'VRIF';
```

Comment: @vquintans So if we want to verify and code review both, how to get it? Thanks!

Comment: @Cheers This information is a little outdated as with actual versions of gerrit the labels are not stored in the database but are configured per project in the project.config file:
https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.7/config-labels.html

Comment: @vquintans So if we need the verified label we should config it in each project, right? Thanks a lot!